# How to change my SQL2012 server name to localhost?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012-express

After I installed SQL 2012 Express, I can't connect to localhost or (local) to local server.

I have to put my computername/instance name in order for me to connect to server.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You should still be able to do `localhost\instancename`

Comment: Corrected, and yes.  That one has bitten me before.

Comment: Here is a possible answer https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/07/13/sql-server-how-to-change-server-name/

Comment: @DiegoDias No, that blog post does not have an answer. Did you actually read it?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes, I read it! In my case I changed the instance name successfully and I thought this post would be helpful

Comment: @AaronBertrand I made a mistake because the query mentioned in the post the author rename variable @@servername to 'ServerName/InstanceName'.

Comment: sorry... none of them are working...

Answer (score 6):

You can't change a named instance to a default instance without reinstalling SQL Server. You can perhaps fool it with client network aliases and/or port redirection, but wouldn't it be just as easy to specify one of the following when connecting?

```
YOUR_PC_NAME\SQLEXPRESS

localhost\SQLEXPRESS

(local)\SQLEXPRESS

.\SQLEXPRESS
```

Comment: @user2502947 this has nothing to do with 2005, 2008 or 2012. If you could use (local) or localhost before, it's because you had a default instance. Now you don't, so you can't. If you installed 2008 with an instance named SQLEXPRESS you wouldn't be able to use (local) or localhost now either.

Comment: oh...  I see. It's cause my instance is not default. I thought I did. Okay. Good to know. Thanks for the info!

Comment: If the instance name is MSSQLSERVER then it is the default name so I do not have to put anything there right?

Comment: @user2502947 Correct, if it's `MSSQLSERVER` then it's the default instance, so you do not need to specify a name. `YOUR_PC_NAME` or `localhost` or `(local)` or `127.0.0.1` or `.` will do. If it doesn't work, you'll need to be more specific than "isn't working" - what is the _exact_ error message?